# How to calculate uncertainty for value with imaginary part?

Tags: error-analysis

I would like to use CKM matrix in Wolfenstein parameterization because I want to keep an imaginary part.

I get $A, \lambda, \bar{\eta}, \bar{\rho}$ from PDG and these values have uncertainty.

I have no problem with calculating uncertainty for the value which is real but I don't know how to calculate one with imaginary part.

PS. I use Mathematica to calculate the uncertainty for values.

Thanks.